# Google Maps API Java Default Zoom

Tags: java, google-maps, zooming

Im just wondering how to set a default zoom on my google maps application in java. I know in Javascript the call is to get the bounds and set the zoom to that, but is there any method of setting a default zoom level in Java (My application starts with an unzoomed look of the world)

Thanks,
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Hiii You can set you Zoom Level Using Below Code In Google Map.

var zoom = 10;
var map;
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat), zoom);
```

Comment: Friend he/she want zooming in Google map, not in OpenLayer.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jappit.com/blog/midmaps-google-maps-java-me-library/
It actually depends on which API u are using in java the above link illustrates the usage of the GoogleMaps Class. if u are using some other class still the logic remains the same as in the above link. if there is no setZoom function in ur class. u might consider using this class or some other class.